# Hibernate @ColumnTransformer How to set user defined key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my Spring boot application I am using hibernate ORM and database as MySql, I have a user entity which has email column. Due to security reason we encrypt all the private informations so I want to encrypt the email using AES encryption (because AES encryption is used in the other component of application).

I was going through hibernate documentation & found @ColumnTransformer can be used for the same.
here is my Users Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String customerNo;

    @NotBlank(message = "email can't be blank")
    @Email(message = "invalid format")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(gmailAddress), 'mySecretKey')", write = "HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'mySecretKey'))")
    private String gmailAddress;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerNo() {
        return customerNo;
    }

    public void setCustomerNo(String customerNo) {
        this.customerNo = customerNo;
    }

    public String getGmailAddress() {
        return gmailAddress;
    }

    public void setGmailAddress(String gmailAddress) {
        this.gmailAddress = gmailAddress;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(LocalDateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(LocalDateTime modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }
}
```

This seems to be working, however I don't want to specify the key as `@ColumnTransformer(read = "AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(gmailAddress), 'mySecretKey')"`

I would like to pass this value as a .key file which is also used by other components of application built on different language such as PHP.

I would like to know if there is a work around for this.

I am intermediate in spring boot and beginner in hibernate. Please do let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: I guess [a custom hibernate type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) or [attribute  converter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) will be suitable for your needs

Comment: @SternK how will u pass "user defined key" to attribute converter?